# How to make UILocalNotification which doesn't launch my app

Tags: ios

I am using UILocalNotification to let a user know something. However, it's for a note for him and it doesn't require any actions in my application.

I set:

```
localNotification setAlertAction:nil]; 
[localNotification setHasAction: NO];
```

So, it shows only in the top of Home screen. However, if the user clicks on it, my app got launched.

Is there a way to create a local notification, which won't launch my app, when it's tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user clicks on a local notification alert, iOS will launch the associated app. This is the expected behaviour of handling local notification. I don't believe you can change it.